# Do the active X-Men have jobs and careers outside of teaching at the school?

Tags: marvel, x-men, super-hero

Sine the 1980s, it’s been commonly seen that most of the adult "active" X-Men lived/live at Xavier's mansion/school in Westchester, and often act as teachers at *Xavier's Institute for Gifted Youngsters.* In the 2000s *X-Men* films, Scott, Jean, and Ororo being teachers is *heavily* implied, but Jean was *also* shown to be a medical doctor. In several comics in the 70s and 80s, we are given example of *non-active* members having outside jobs; Hank McCoy/Beast was a research scientist and teacher, by many accounts...

[image]

Alex worked for the government; Warren Worthington ran a multi-million dollar company for a while; even Scott, for the limited time he was away after Jean's death, worked a regular job as a ships crewman, and then as a pilot in Alaska (where he met Madelyn Pryor)...

[image]

[image]

When they are **with** the X-Men, though, we rarely hear of other "work commitments". I searched for other viable 616 examples, but came up a bit short.

So I was wondering: do "active" X-Men hold down "civilian" jobs, or are they seen to be employed by the school?

Granted, Charles has a lot of investments, and the school itself *should* make money, but considering how many missions they are on and how few students are seen there on the regular outside of the films, it's never clearly explained.

Comment: In the past, not as a rule. There may have been exceptions. Right now(2020) hell no. With them all living on a sci-fi commune everyone pitches in but none of it would probably count as a "regular job".

Answer (score 3):

Any X-Man that is active on the team almost never has a "job".  You can read or flip through hundreds of X-men stories and not even find a hint of any sort of day job.

The comics are a bit hit or miss on X-men being "teachers".  They vast majority of the comics before the Fox X-men movies don't mention the school much.  After the Fox movies the comics do suddenly show the school full of kids, just like is seen in the movies.

In reality, the school would have lots of teachers...the real kind that teach a subject.  They might even be low powered folks that can like ''levitate a piece of paper".

Mostly though, they just say Professor X is rich, and don't think about it much.